# Issue in rendering remote data in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am creating a mock ionic project , where I need to display the post detail,Everything works fine except when I try to render the post object property like

```
{{post.title}}
```

In post detail template, I receive following error,

```
Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

the component code snippet is ,

```js
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public postdetailservice: PostDetailService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getPostDetail();
  }
  getPostDetail() {
    let id = '57f8e0797224ae55254878b6';
    this.postdetailservice.getDetail(id).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.post = data;
        console.log('Post Detail', this.post.title);
      },
      err => {
        this.errormessage = 'Post Details Not Found';
        console.log(this.errormessage, err);
      });
  }
```

post service code that makes api calls,

```js
  getDetail(postId): Observable<[any]> {
    let url = postUrl + postId + '/detail';
    return this.http.post(url,{},options)
    .map(this.getData)
    .catch(this.handleError);

  }

  private getData(res: Response){
        let detail = res.json();
        console.log(detail.post);
        return detail.post;

  }
  handleError(error: any):ErrorObservable{
    console.error('Servor Error!', error);
    return Observable.throw(error || 'Server Error');
  }
```

I solved it by using elvis operator , But I need to know is there any better way to remove this error as I need to do property binding in lot of places in html file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `post` data isn't defined yet when the view is rendered, as you're still waiting to get it. You could either use the `?` operator or wrap it in an `*ngIf`

```
{{post?.title}}

// OR

<div *ngIf="post">
  {{post.title}}
</div>
```